# Combined Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Very new to MYSQL, but how can I combine these two queries to show the SUM(total) of the type = 'i' minus SUM(total) of the type = 'p'.

```
SELECT userid, SUM(total)
FROM invoices
WHERE type = 'i'
GROUP BY 1

SELECT userid, SUM(total)
FROM invoices
WHERE type = 'p'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `case` expression

```
SELECT userid, 
    SUM(case when type = 'i' then total else 0 end) typei,
    SUM(case when type = 'p' then total else 0 end) typep,
    SUM(case when type = 'i' then total else 0 end) - SUM(case when type = 'p' then total else 0 end) as diff
FROM invoices
GROUP BY userid
```

Or you could write it as

```
SUM(case when type = 'i' then total when type = 'p' then -1 * total else 0 end) as diff
```

Edit: To filter the results produced by aggregation you could use having clause

```
SELECT userid, 
    SUM(case when type = 'i' then total else 0 end) typei,
    SUM(case when type = 'p' then total else 0 end) typep,
    SUM(case when type = 'i' then total else 0 end) - SUM(case when type = 'p' then total else 0 end) as diff
FROM invoices
GROUP BY userid
HAVING diff > 0
```

Comment: Or `if(type = 'i', total, 0)` with MySQL.

Comment: Is there any way to only show the results if `diff is > 0`?

Comment: @thomaskessel see updated answer use `having` clause for that purpose